# MySQL slow log configuration

Tags: mysql, configuration, performance, slow-log

Is there a way of making MySQL slow logs to start new log file every day ?
At the moment its just a single large file, and have to grep lines for every day. It would be much more convenient to have separate files for every days slow logs.

Do I have to configure a my.cnf or some linux feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone is used to this one, the good old text file.

Just run the following to flush a slow log everyday

STEP 01) Turn off the slow query log

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
```

STEP 02) Copy the text file

```
cat slow-query.log | gzip > /logs/slow-query-`date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M"`.log.gz
```

STEP 03) Truncate the file to zero bytes

```
echo -n > slow-query.log
```

STEP 04) Turn on the slow query log

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```

You could switch to `log-output=TABLE` and deal with it as a Table to Query.

STEP 01) Convert mysql.slow_log from CSV to MyISAM

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

STEP 02) Index the table

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log ADD INDEX (start_time);
```

STEP 03) Activate log format to be TABLE

```
[mysqld]
log-output=TABLE
```

STEP 04) `service mysql restart`

Once you startup mysqld, the slow log entries are recorded in the MyISAM table mysql.slow_log;

To rotate out the entries before midnight, you could something like this:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
SET @dt = NOW();
SET @dtstamp = DATE_FORMAT(@dt,'%Y%m%d_%H%i%S');
SET @midnight = DATE(@dt) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log RENAME mysql.slow_log_old;
CREATE TABLE mysql.slow_log LIKE mysql.slow_log_old;
INSERT INTO mysql.slow_log SELECT * FROM mysql.slow_log_old WHERE start_time >= @midnight;
DELETE FROM mysql.slow_log_old WHERE start_time >= @midnight;
SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE mysql.slow_log_old RENAME mysql.slow_log_',@dtstamp);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```

and that's all for slow logs...

Comment: Cheers for useful and quick reply, as always. My only concern is about FLUSH LOGS on servers with replication slave or master. Will that influence bin-logs or relay-logs ?

Comment: FLUSH LOGS will only closing the current binary log and opena new one. If you have replication, the slave will keep pace with the master's log rotation.

Comment: I tried both this script and logrotate, and non of them seem to work. It turned out that flush logs did not work. I started new question on that:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16339/mysql-flush-logs-unknown-error

Answer (score 5):

**Update**
As Aaron points out, there is the chance the copy-and-truncate can miss some entries. So the safer method is to move and `FLUSH`.

**Original**

[This article](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/the-correct-approach-to-rolling-mysql-logs-2010-02-22/) has the basic principle to rotating the slow query log that I use. Basically you need to copy the slow log to a new file, then truncate the contents of the slow.log:

```
cp log/slow.log log/slow.log.`date +%M`; > log/slow.log
```

If you just move the slow log to a new file and creating a new  'slow.log', it won't work because the moved file still has the same inode, and mysql still has it open. I suppose moving the file and then issuing a `FLUSH SLOW LOGS` command would work, as that closes the file and reopens, but I find the copy-and-truncate to be just as effective and doesn't require logging into mysql.

His article mentions using logrotate in Linux, but I just made a cronjob to run once a day at midnight to do this for me.

Also, to address the issue of replication on `FLUSH LOGS`:

> FLUSH LOGS, FLUSH MASTER, FLUSH SLAVE, and FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK (with or without a table list) are not written to the binary log in any case because they would cause problems if replicated to a slave. [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html)

So no, since those statements are not written to the binary log, it will not interfere with replication. For your purposes I would specify `FLUSH SLOW LOGS` to only close/open the slow query log.

Comment: Copy and truncate can miss entries.  mv + FLUSH LOGS will not.

Comment: I agree with Aaron.  Moving it is just some file system shuffling so quicker as well (assuming it's on the same FS) .  mysqld keeps the file pointer to the one you just mv'd until you flush logs

Comment: Good points, both of you. Obviously in my environment I have not been bothered with the possibility of missing <1 second of slow logs, but to avoid a potential 'bite-me-in-the-***' I'll probably switch it myself.

Comment: But if you have replication happening, will the FLUSH LOGS do influence it some way ?

Comment: @Katafaikas added a bit about replication..

Answer (score 4):

use Logrotate.d to daily rotate the files and keep as many days as you want or move them off...then issue a flush-logs from the same script to get MySQL to start a new file....having that in log rotate, set to daily should get you what you want..

I am hoping someday they implement something similar to 'expire_log_days' for debugging logs like genlog and slow log