# MySQL flush logs, unknown error

Tags: mysql, logs, performance, slow-log

I gave been trying to solve this for few days now, and cant seem to figure this out.

I have been trying to set log rotation for mysql slow using linux logrotate feature, and my script seems to get stuck on `mysqladmin flush-logs`.
So I logged into mysql and just entered `FLUSH LOGS;`. Not surprisingly I get an error:

```
mysql> flush logs;
ERROR 1105 (HY000): Unknown error
```

Now I have been going around asking for ideas, but none seem to work, its not permissions, not owners, not SELinux

I know that there used to be some bug, like in 2005 or 2008 ... but its 2012, I assume its fixed.

So if anyone has any ideas, would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might not be able to assume the bug is fixed... try to track down a bug report and check the status.

Comment: Two questions : 1) What version of MySQL are you using? 2) Did you recently upgrade?

Comment: MySQL version - 5.5.21. I did not upgrade recently. OS: CentOS - 6 . Kernel 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Next two questions: Did you ever run `flush logs` before? If you did, did you get this same error message `ERROR 1105 (HY000): Unknown error `?

Comment: Let me restart my previous question: You have MySQL 5.5.21. Did you recently upgrade to MySQL 5.5.21 from a previous version ???

Comment: It was MySQL 5.5.21 from the first day of installation, and the FLUSH LOGS; used to work fine. For some reason it stopped working now, when I tried using scripts.

Comment: [This](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64988) seems to indicate that there is an issue with dotdeb.org builds of mysql. Perhaps it's related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL on Debian 6 squeeze stable with vMySQL-5.5 then there is a known issue mentioned about dotdeb packaging:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64988

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting the permissions for one error-log file. You find the location using:

```
echo "show global variables like 'log_error';" | mysql -u root -p
```

And the fix is as trivial as

```
chown mysql $error_log_file
```

Worked for me on `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for debian-linux-gnu`
Found at http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,584361